# Generar tabla en excel comparando valores de una lista

Tags: excel, excel-2013

Supongamos que tenemos la siguiente tabla de excel

```
ID   Dato
1     bvm
2     cin
3     cmv_s
4     ada
5     ada_s
6     cin_s
7     cmv
8     bvm_s
```

Realizando algún proceso, llego a que las únicas variable que me sirven son bvm, cmv, ada, cin. Por lo tanto, me gustaría generar la siguiente tabla en excel

```
ID    Dato     Process
1     bvm         1
2     cin         1
3     cmv_s       0
4     ada         1
5     ada_s       0
6     cin_s       0
7     cmv         1 
8     bvm_s       0
```

En este caso, lo puedo hacer yo, pero si tuviera 1000 variables no seria tan sencillo, como puedo generar esta tabla?

Answer (score 1):

bienvenido a stackoverflow en español; las variables que te sirven puedes enumerarlas en una tabla aparte (tabla 2) para que puedas buscarlas desde la tabla que tienes (tabla 1) y deseas que muestre 0 o 1.
Para esto vamos hacer uso de 2 funciones muy conocidas:

**contar.si()** : Para verificar si cualquier elemento de la tabla 1 se encuentra en la tabla 2.
**si()** : En caso la función contar.si() es mayor que cero, mostraremos 1 caso contrario mostramos 0.

Teniendo en cuenta que nuestros datos de la tabla 1 comienza en A2 y B2 porque en A1 y B1 se encuentra el encabezado de la tabla 1, la formula a escribir en la celda C2 sería.

```
=SI(CONTAR.SI($E$2:$E$5;B2)>0;1;0)
```

Los variables que nos interesa se encuentra en el rango E2:E5

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre realizar una validación con la función `SI` y utilizando la función `O` dentro de la prueba lógica.

```
=SI(O(B1="bvm",B1="cmv",B1="ada",B1="cin"),1,0)
```

De esta forma se estaría comparando si el valor de la celda **B1** es igual a cualquiera de estas cuatro variables, muestra un 1, en caso contrario, muestra un 0.

Con esto en mente, sólo sería necesario hacer doble click en la esquina inferior derecha de la celda **C1** para que se autocomplete la fórmula en las celdas de la columna **C**.